# I'm trying to write a program to accept and display an array using diffrent functions, but I'm unable to print the array

Tags: arrays, c, function

The code i have written down:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void get()
{
    int i,a[50],limit;
    printf("enter the limit:");
    scanf("%d",&limit); 
    
    printf("enter the array");
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    
}

void display()
{
    int i,a[50],limit;
    printf("the array is");
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }

}

int main(void)
{
   int i,a[50],limit;
   get(); 
   display(); 
   
}
```

Output:

```
enter the limit:5
enter the array1
2
3
4
5
the array is1   2       3       4       5       7143534 7209061   7536756 6488156 7077985 2949228 7471201 3019901633014777  7864421 101     0       0       -707682512      32767     -317320272      573     -690587167      32767   -317320288        573     -317325312      573     47      064       0       0       0       4       0       0       0-317325312       573     -690580068      32767   -31732531573      2       0       47      0       64      51      -1799357088       125     961877721       32758   3       32758     961957944       32758   -317168624      573     -706746576        32767
```

Comment: Your arrays are local variables, isn't it? So there is no link in between them all.

Comment: Your array a is a local variable in each function. The content will not be copied between these. You need to pass the array as parameter or use a global variable.

Comment: The ```limit``` variable and ```a``` array don't magically get from your ```get``` function to your ```display``` function, you need to givie this parameter to your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `int i,a[50],limit;` in each of your functions, these variables are *local* to the functions.

For example the `limit` variable declared in `get` is totally unrelated to the `limit` variable declared in `set` etc. They just happen to have the same name.

You ether need to declare these variables as global variables (poor design), or redesign your code differently, for example by passing those variables as parameters.

All this is explained in the first chapters of your beginner's C text book.

Example using global variables (poor design)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i, a[50], limit;   // global variables visible
                       // from all functions

void get()
{
  printf("enter the limit:");
  scanf("%d", &limit);

  printf("enter the array");
  for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }
}

void display()
{
  printf("the array is");
  for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\t", a[i]);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  get();
  display();
}
```